# Import new users from a CSV file in a location and add users in it to a QAD security group

Tags: powershell, quest

EDIT: I think I solved it?

```
$dir = "H:\ScriptLibrary\KB4_Users_Target\KB4Users*" 
$filter = "*.csv" 
$latest = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Filter $filter | Sort-Object 
LastAccessTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1

$list = Get-content $latest

$strGroupName = "CN=Eddie Play 
Ground,OU=TestAccounts,OU=GlobalApps,DC=global,DC=scj,DC=loc"
Foreach($user in $list)
{add-qadgroupmember -identity $strGroupName -member $user}
```

But now am getting an access denied error, which is something on our side I need to dive into.

I am trying to import the newest csv file (users list) and add them to a known QAD security group.
The newest file will be uploaded daily and I want to automate a script in QAD to add the new users to the target group.
What I have so far is this and I've been all over and keep getting different recommendations and am stuck here. The last part of the script populates the group just fine, I am just trying to get the newest list from the file location and import that CSV.

Ideally, I would then like to move that file I imported to a subfolder where it is hosted (D:\Scripts\KB$\KB4Processed)

```
$dir = "D:\Scripts\KB4
#$list = Get-content D:\Scripts\KB4\KB4Users*" 
$filter = "*.csv" 
$latest = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Filter $filter | Sort-Object 
LastWriteTime - 
       Descending | Select-Object -First 1 
$latest.Name $OutFile = 'D:\Scripts\KB4\KB4USersProcess.csv' 
  
Import-Csv -Path $latest | ForEach-Object {

$strGroupName = 
"CN=.GroupName,OU=DistributionGroups,DC=global,DC=mydomain,DC=loc"
$list =D:\Scripts\KB4\KB4USersProcess.csv
Foreach($user in $list)
{add-qadgroupmember -identity $strGroupName -member $user}`
```

I am expecting to import the latest file of users and then add them to a QAD group

Comment: Welcome to SO, Eddie. What happens when this script is run? My guess is that there would be error messages. Please describe in greater detail how this code does not work. Which debugger are you using to step through the code? Microsoft Visual Studio Code has a debugger and it is the right price.

Comment: I get an error that the file cannot be found. No. debugger and I have tied creating several files in a test file location that this script would see, but only want to import the newest one. It won't. 

We are going to be loading users who pass training to be able to use an application. That application access is managed by QAD group membership. 
It will be loaded daily to a hosted location. I want the script to be able to import the newest file only, read the user list from that file and add them to the group. 
I am able to edit the file loc. in it and add OK, as in the bottom portion.

Comment: I also get an error with the $outfile CMDLT

Comment: At D:\Scripts\AddMemberBulk (knowB4) Test.ps1:6 char:14
+ $latest.Name $OutFile = 'D:\Scripts\KB4\KB4USersProcess.csv'
+              ~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token '$OutFile' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken

Comment: Please edit the question and paste in the error message(s) as text.  They are far more difficult to read in a comment.

Comment: The error message indicates a problem on the line starting with `$latest.Name $OutFile =...`. This is not valid syntax in PowerShell. What is the intent of this statement? Should that statement be `$OutFile = Join-Path -Path $dir -ChildPath 'KB4USersProcess.csv'`? Why is `$latest.Name` used?

Comment: What I understood this to do is to overwrite the file with the new date and name to be process by the next for each line. Really, get the latest file despite what date format someone might use to upload it. 
I am also new to this, so if there's a better way to do what I ultimately need to do, I am am all ears. I have been through several suggestions and am stuck at this juncture.

Comment: SO is a place where developers help developers. If you want to be a developer, you are going to need to step up and learn some PowerShell. There are too many fundamental issues here that the only way to overcome them would be learning PowerShell or getting someone to write the code for you. That is not what SO is about.

Comment: That's why I'm here. To learn. :(

Comment: Ok, then, what do you make of the error message `Test.ps1:6 char:14 + $latest.Name $OutFile =...`? What is the purpose of this line of code? Do you have a debugger? If so, which one? If not, please use Microsoft Visual Studio Code. It is the right price. https://code.visualstudio.com/download

Comment: I know outfile is an incorrect CMDLT, and I have been researching the right way to get what I need. I got that syntax from another post here in SO. It was recommended as a verified answer. I've removed it since and am stuck. If I have a file, I am able to populate the group without issue using the bottom 2 lines of the script. I run this all the time, but now they want to automate a user list upload and to run this as a scheduled task, but I get lost on importing the most current file they will upload. There are about 100 different answers and none seem to work for me.

Comment: What do you mean that "`outfile` is an incorrect CMDLT"? Did you mean `cmdlet`? `$outfile in this code is a variable that is assigned a string value. Is that the filename you are expecting to be the output?

Comment: Hi lit, again, thank you for taking the time to help a noob. My intent was to take the most current file and export to another location and then pull the user data from the new location, because that is what I in my limited knowledge have been able to do so far. I have tried to figure out how to Import only the newest csv and then populate the group that way, but only get deeper in the weeds. I landed on the above in my research how to do this and that is how you and I started discussing. I know what I posted doesn't work, and I don't know the right path to go down to do what I need it to do.

Comment: Remove the `$latest.Name` from before `$OutFile =...`. Run the first five lines in the debugger and report by editing the question what the values of $dir, $filter, $latest, and $OutFile are. If you cannot use a debugger, start a new .ps1 script file with just those lines and print them out at the end.

Comment: $path="H:\ScriptLibrary\KB4_Users_Target\KB4Users*"
$filter = "*.csv"
$latest=Get-ChildItem $path | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $True}
ForEach($dir in $latest)
{
Get-ChildItem  "$path\$($dir.name)" -Recurse |
Where-Object {($_.LastWriteTime -gt ([DateTime]::Now.Adddays(-1))) -and ($_.PSIsContainer -eq $False) } |
Select-Object @{l='Folder';e={$dir.Name}},Name,LastWriteTime |
Sort-Object  -pro LastWriteTime -Descending |
Select -First 1
}

Out-File -FilePath :\ScriptLibrary\KB4_Users_Target_Complete\KB4Users_Processed.csv

Comment: I was able to get this to find the most recent file and write a new csv to a location, but it didn't pull in the users in the source file and add them to the output file that I can target to add people to the group. This part of my script is working though, if the csv has a list of users. 
$list = Import-Csv -Path 'H:\ScriptLibrary\KB4_Users_Target _Complete\KB4Users_Processed.csv'

$strGroupName = "CN=Eddie PlayGround,OU=TestAccounts,OU=GlobalApps,DC=global,DC=scj,DC=loc"
Foreach($user in $list)
{add-qadgroupmember -identity $strGroupName -member $user}

Comment: Fantastic! Great to hear that you got it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED:

```
import-module ActiveRolesManagementShell
Connect-QADService -service #replace hostname or servername where ARS is running -proxy

$dir = "H:\ScriptLibrary\KB4_Users_Target\KB4Users*" #edit this to the file's location
$filter = "*.csv" 
$latest = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Filter $filter | Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1

$list = Get-Content $latest
#this is the GAD group to add users to
$strGroupName = "CN=Eddie Play Ground,OU=TestAccounts,OU=GlobalApps,DC=global,DC=Mydomain,DC=loc"
Foreach($user in $list)
{add-qadgroupmember -identity $strGroupName -member $user}
```

I was able to edit the files and target only the one with the most recent updates and then add them to the group I needed to.